# How do/can I convert .ebl files to any common audio format?

Tags: conversion

I have a number of `.ebl` files which I want to convert to any common audio format (`wav` or `aif` for example). Finder recognises them as "Emu EmulatorX Sample" while `file` (unix) says they are "IFF data".

Comment: A quick Google says it can depend on where the file came from as to whether it will convert. Some of them are encrypted/proprietary. Word is that [Translator](http://www.chickensys.com/products2/translator/index.html) by ChickenSys can do it, but I've no experience with that app.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for trying to help, I found that as well. I was hoping to find a cheaper solution (Translator is $150, and I will probably use it once)

Answer (score 0):

Ive open EBl files this way.

Mac
1 open audacity
2 on your left right side click on "FILE"
form the drop down menu select "IMPORT"
from that small drop down menu select "IMPORT RAW DATA"
3 select your ebl file and open it
4 a small menu will show up saying "IMPORT RAW DATA"
SELECT encoding: sIGNED 32-BIT PCM
Byte Order: Little-endian
Chanels: 2 channel (stereo)
start offset 0
amount to import: 100%
Sample rate 44100hz.
then press import

NOTE  a few files will be mono. i just separate the stereo channels and select the ones that dont have the white noise noise. ( do this at low volumes

i am still figuring out the IMPORT RAW DATA menu
but this are the best setting that are working for me.

you can also chain this process in audacity. it will  covert vast amount of files automatically